# ID3DX10Mesh::CloneMesh

Tags: c++, directx-10

I'm trying to copy mesh in DirectX10. I wrote this:

```
HR(mesh->CloneMesh(mesh->GetFlags(),data.GetPosSemantic(),data.GetInputElementDesc(),
        data.GetDescCount(),&mMesh));
```

but when i try to render the mesh nothing appers on the screen.

when i write

```
mMesh = mesh;
```

There are no problems with the rendering(unless when I release  "mesh" ).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to duplicate the mesh without any changes, you should use the second approach and call then `mMesh->AddRef()` to declare the data is owned by two pointers (better idea is to use some kind of smart pointers - COM or `boost::shared_ptr` adapted to COM-like objects).

But the first case should work too - what is the `data` object about?

Comment: Thanks it worked. I think I should reed more abouct COM. I use the data object to pass the input declarations, postion semantic name and the number of the declarations.Few days ago i saw that it is unnecessary, but I haven't removed it, yet.